update laravel10->11 livewire 2->3 Error with scripts Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
I have a Laravel project in which I have livewire, I tried to update them (Laravel from 10 to 11 and livewire from 2 to 3) following the guides for Laravel and for livewire.
After updating every packages and configs I started my project with laragon and vite as usual but got this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<', and no js works on any pages!
After 2 days of searching on the internet and trying stuff in my project I found out that the error happened because of @livewireScripts()/@livewireStyles() in my layout, after removing them I didn't have the error but my js scripts would not work after that (which is normal I guess)
So could someone please help me on this, I really don't understand this.
Here are some files. I know it is a lot and I am sorry, I don't even know if those are relevant enough, I am just lost.
app.js before:
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js';
import Alpine from 'alpinejs';
import './bootstrap';
import './alpine';
import './data';
import './doc';
import './filter';

import { popoverinit } from './popover';
import '../sass/app.scss';
let colors;
window.Alpine = Alpine;
Alpine.start();

app.js after (deleted alpine start as it comes automatically with livewire 3 as said in the docs):
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js';
import './bootstrap';
import './data';
import './doc';
import './filter';

import { popoverinit } from './popover';
import '../sass/app.scss';
import { livewire_hot_reload } from 'virtual:livewire-hot-reload';

livewire_hot_reload();

vite.config.mjs:
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'url';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import livewire from '@defstudio/vite-livewire-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    sourcemap: false,
    minify: false,
  },
  plugins: [
    laravel({
      input: ['resources/js/app.js', 'resources/js/update_product.js', 'resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/Vue/main.js', 'resources/js/charts/product.js'],
      refresh: true,
    }),
    vue(),
    livewire({
      refresh: ['resources/sass/app.scss'],
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      { find: '@composition', replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL('./resources/js/Vue/composition', import.meta.url)) },
      { find: '@node_modules', replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL('./node_modules', import.meta.url)) },
    ],
  },
});

config/livewire.php:
<?php
return[
    'class_namespace' => 'App\\Http\\Livewire',
    'view_path' => resource_path('views/livewire'),
    'layout' => 'layouts.app',
    'asset_url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
    // new ones that came with livewire 3
    'legacy_model_binding' => false,
    'inject_assets' => true,
    'inject_morph_markers' => true,
    'navigate' => [
        'show_progress_bar' => true,
        'progress_bar_color' => '#22dd99',
    ],
];

layouts/app-livewire.blade.php before:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
    <title>My site</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="{{ asset('favicons/favicon-96x96.png') }}">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="{{ asset('favicons/favicon-32x32.png') }}">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{{ asset('favicons/favicon-16x16.png') }}">

    @vite(['resources/js/app.js', 'resources/sass/app.scss'])
    <!-- Resources -->
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/xy.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/locales/fr_FR.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/percent.js"></script>

    @livewireStyles()
    @stack('styles')


    <style>
        .swal2-container {
            z-index: 2100;
            margin-top: 4em;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    @include('partials.header')
    <div class="leftpanel">
        @include('partials.sidebar')
    </div>


    <div class="rightpanel">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
            @yield('header')
            <div class="content">

                @yield('content')
            </div>
            @include('partials.footer')
        </div>
    </div>

    @livewireScripts()

    @include('partials.scripts')

    @include('partials.messages')

    @stack('scripts')
</body>

</html>

layouts/app-livewire.blade.php after:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
    <title>My site</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="{{ asset('favicons/favicon-96x96.png') }}">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="{{ asset('favicons/favicon-32x32.png') }}">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{{ asset('favicons/favicon-16x16.png') }}">

    @vite(['resources/js/app.js', 'resources/sass/app.scss'])
    <!-- Resources -->
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/xy.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/locales/fr_FR.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/percent.js"></script>

    @stack('styles')
</head>

<body>
    @include('partials.header')
    <div class="leftpanel">
        @include('partials.sidebar')
    </div>


    <div class="rightpanel">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
            @yield('header')
            <div class="content">

                @yield('content')
            </div>
            @include('partials.footer')
        </div>
    </div>

    @include('partials.scripts')

    @include('partials.messages')

    @stack('scripts')
</body>

</html>

view.blade.php (scripts part) before:
<div>
... my view
@push('scripts')
        <script type="module">
            const regex = /[éèêëïçùô]/i;

            $(document).on('input', '#newName, #editName', function() {
                if (regex.test($(this).val())) {
                    $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
                    $(this).css('box-shadow', '0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(220, 53, 69, 0.25)');
                } else {
                    $(this).css('border', '1px solid #86b7fe');
                    $(this).css('box-shadow', '0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(13, 110, 253, 0.25)');
                }
            });

            $(document).on('show.bs.modal', '#modal', function(e) {
                const btn = e.relatedTarget;

                if (btn.id === 'editBtn') {
                    $('.modal-title').text('Modifier personnel');
                    $('#newName').hide();

                    const editNameInput = $('#editName');
                    editNameInput.show();
                    editNameInput.val(btn.getAttribute('pName'));
                    editNameInput.attr('pId', btn.getAttribute('pId'));
                } else {
                    $('.modal-title').text('Nouveau personnel');
                    $('#editName').hide();

                    const newNameInput = $('#newName');
                    newNameInput.show();
                    newNameInput.val('');
                }
            });

            $(document).on('shown.bs.modal', '#modal', function(e) {
                const btn = e.relatedTarget;

                if (btn.id === 'editBtn') {
                    $('#editName').trigger('focus');
                } else {
                    $('#newName').trigger('focus');
                }
            });

            $(document).on('keyup', '#newName, #editName', function(e) {
                if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                    if (regex.test($(this).val())) {
                        Swal.fire({
                            icon: 'error',
                            toast: true,
                            text: 'Les caractères spéciaux ne sont pas autorisés',
                            position: 'top-right',
                            showConfirmButton: false,
                            timer: 3000
                        })
                        return;
                    }
                    const modal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(document.getElementById('modal'));
                    modal.hide();
                    if ($(this).attr('id') === 'newName') {
                        @this.addPersonnel($(this).val());
                    } else {
                        @this.editPersonnel($(this).attr('pId'), $(this).val());
                    }
                }
            });

            $(document).on('click', '#deleteBtn', function() {
                if (confirm(`Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer ce personnel: ${$(this).attr('pName')}? `)) {
                    @this.deletePersonnel($(this).attr('pId'));
                }
            });
        </script>
    @endpush
</div>

view.blade.php (scripts part) after:
<div>
...my view
</div>
@script
    <script type="module">
            const regex = /[éèêëïçùô]/i;

            $(document).on('input', '#newName, #editName', function() {
                if (regex.test($(this).val())) {
                    $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
                    $(this).css('box-shadow', '0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(220, 53, 69, 0.25)');
                } else {
                    $(this).css('border', '1px solid #86b7fe');
                    $(this).css('box-shadow', '0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(13, 110, 253, 0.25)');
                }
            });

            $(document).on('show.bs.modal', '#modal', function(e) {
                const btn = e.relatedTarget;

                if (btn.id === 'editBtn') {
                    $('.modal-title').text('Modifier personnel');
                    $('#newName').hide();

                    const editNameInput = $('#editName');
                    editNameInput.show();
                    editNameInput.val(btn.getAttribute('pName'));
                    editNameInput.attr('pId', btn.getAttribute('pId'));
                } else {
                    $('.modal-title').text('Nouveau personnel');
                    $('#editName').hide();

                    const newNameInput = $('#newName');
                    newNameInput.show();
                    newNameInput.val('');
                }
            });

            $(document).on('shown.bs.modal', '#modal', function(e) {
                const btn = e.relatedTarget;

                if (btn.id === 'editBtn') {
                    $('#editName').trigger('focus');
                } else {
                    $('#newName').trigger('focus');
                }
            });

            $(document).on('keyup', '#newName, #editName', function(e) {
                if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                    if (regex.test($(this).val())) {
                        Swal.fire({
                            icon: 'error',
                            toast: true,
                            text: 'Les caractères spéciaux ne sont pas autorisés',
                            position: 'top-right',
                            showConfirmButton: false,
                            timer: 3000
                        })
                        return;
                    }
                    const modal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(document.getElementById('modal'));
                    modal.hide();
                    if ($(this).attr('id') === 'newName') {
                        $wire.addPersonnel($(this).val());
                    } else {
                        $wire.editPersonnel($(this).attr('pId'), $(this).val());
                    }
                }
            });

            $(document).on('click', '#deleteBtn', function() {
                if (confirm(`Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer ce personnel: ${$(this).attr('pName')}? `)) {
                    $wire.deletePersonnel($(this).attr('pId'));
                }
            });
    </script>
@endscript

controller.php (just to show the render method) before:
public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.view')->extends('layouts.app-livewire');
    }

controller.php after:
#[Layout('layouts.app-livewire')]
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.view');
    }



and my console:


Take a look at the Network tab to see what really is loaded onto the page.

Just a stab in the dark here, but Livewire 3 and AlpineJS loads its javascript resources itself from something like /livewire/livewire.js in the footer. If this route does not exist, it will return your 404 page which will start with <. Could be the reason you are getting this error. Check your network tab and look at what is returned.

Hi thanks for the fast reply, I added 2 ss from the netwrok tab, hope it will be helpful.
@RichardLeishman do you mean I have to add a route in the project for that specific file?

Hi a little update, as you can see livewire.js is not loaded at all, I found this: Livewire::setScriptRoute(function ($handle) {
return Route::get('/custom/livewire/livewire.js', $handle);
});
and after publishing the assets I see that a livewire.js is created at public/vendor/livewire/livewire.js, so I added this route like that:
Livewire::setScriptRoute(function ($handle) {
return Route::get('/public/vendor/livewire/livewire.js', $handle);
}); in web.php and also api.php but none worked. maybe someone will find?

and 1 detail, I went back because it didn't work, removed a lot of things, like @livewireScripts in my layout, inject_assets in my config/livewire.js, also deleted vendor in public and stopped publishing assets... when I go to url livewire/livewire.js I get the correct file but still get the same error, I still don't see the livewire.js file loaded in the network tab
